# Resolucion ecuaciones Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Tengo una ecuación con dos expresiones `A=(Pu/2)+Mu/(lw-x))` y `B=0.85*280*b*x`, donde `A=B` y `x` es la incógnita. Como puedo resolver usando la librería sympy?

```
import sympy as sym
x=sym.Symbol('x')
lw= 5.65    #largo muro
Pu= 258.7   #toneladas
Mu= 1.525   #tonelada-metro
Vu= 128     #tonelada
b=0.3
result=sym.solve([((Pu/2)+Mu/(lw-x)),0.85*280*b*x],x)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que las dos expresiones son el miembro izquierdo y derecho de una ecuación lo único que tienes que hacer es pasar uno de los miembros al otro lado. 
A=B  sería... A-B=0. y resuleves (A-B) con sympy. Aquí te dejo el código:

```
import sympy as sym
x=sym.Symbol('x')
lw= 5.65    #largo muro
Pu= 258.7   #toneladas
Mu= 1.525   #tonelada-metro
Vu= 128     #tonelada
b=0.3
result=sym.solve([((Pu/2)+Mu/(lw-x))-(0.85*280*b*x)])
print(result)
```

Comment: que pena no me hice entender bien no son dos ecuaciones las dos partes que aparen allí es una igualación es decir una sola ecuacion a resolver con incognita x

Comment: Vale, entonces es aún más sencillo, sólo tienes que restar la segunda ecuación a la primera. Editaré la respuesta y agregaré la solución.Saludos)

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa es `Eq(izquierdo, derecha)`:

```py
import sympy as sym
x = sym.Symbol('x')
lw = 5.65    #largo muro
Pu = 258.7   #toneladas
Mu = 1.525   #tonelada-metro
Vu = 128     #tonelada
b = 0.3
resultado = sym.solve([sym.Eq(((Pu/2)+Mu/(lw-x)),0.85*280*b*x)],x)
print(resultado)
```